# Cannot encode to UTF-8 in JNI

Tags: java, android, encoding, utf-8, java-native-interface

I'm trying to return jstring encoded with UTF-8, but app crashes and JNI writes out error:

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal continuation byte 0x30
```

My snippet:

```
jstring Java_tgio_rncryptor_RNCryptorNative_generateKey(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, const jstring salt_, const jstring password_)
 {
    const char *salt = env->GetStringUTFChars(salt_, 0);
    const char *password = env->GetStringUTFChars(password_, 0);
    RNCryptor *cryptor = new RNCryptor();
    string value = (char * )cryptor->generateKey(salt, password).data();
    delete cryptor;
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(salt_, salt);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(password_, password);
    return env->NewStringUTF(value.c_str());
}
```

Also tried:

```
const char *returning = env->GetStringUTFChars(env->NewStringUTF(value.c_str()), 0);
return env->NewStringUTF(returning);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

`cryptor->generateKey` returns `SecByteBlock`, a sequence of bytes. While casting to `(char *)` and constructing a `std::string` make sense because they do not deal only with text, `jstring` holds text (from the Unicode character set in the UTF-16 encoding).

You code tries to convert non-text bytes to a Java string. If you really want to do that you have to use a character set and encoding for which any sequence of values 0-255 are valid. (CP437 would be one.)

But instead, you could keep the data in a datatype closer to what it is: return  a Java `byte[]`. Then on the Java side, you could convert the sequence of bytes in to [Base 64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html), if you want to pass the key around as a string.

In general, cryptographic algorithms operate on byte sequences or blocks. It's only the application or wrapper functions that deal with text. You'll have check if RNCryptor does that for you but it doesn't look like that to me.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code for UTF-8**

```
  try {
URLEncoder.encode(yourValue, "UTF-8")

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I also tried this in Java source code, but with no results. :(

Answer (score 0):

Not all bytes are valid printable characters and most are not valid unicode characters. Standard practice when it is necessary to encode a byte array to a string is to use Base64 or hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with returning `jcharArray` instead of `jstring`:

```
     env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(salt_, salt);
     env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(password_, password);
     char array[1024];
     strcpy(array, value.c_str());
     jcharArray charArr = env->NewCharArray(1024);
     env->SetCharArrayRegion(charArr, 0, 1024, (jchar *) array);
     return charArr;
```

And I just did `String.valueOf(arr)` in Java source code, and printed it.

Comment: In Java, a char or jchar is a UTF-16 code unit. You seem to be combining two bytes into a jchar. You could run into trouble if that jchar value is not a valid UTF-16 code unit or if it is a [surrogate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isSurrogate-char-) not followed or preceded by a corresponding surrogate. I think you are also over-reading your `array` by 100%.

Comment: Yeah, it can be improved, but it's more or less right structure, I think. Tell me your suggestions, if you want.

Comment: So you're suggesting to use byte[] instead of char[] ?

Comment: https://github.com/TGIO/RNCryptorNative/commit/f6e2c0f8e9d06a0c87452e79a7b58bf5cca2f3cc 

I just tried it, you can see and tell me your opinion

Comment: The native implementation looks okay but I'm baffled by `new String(arr, "UTF-16")`. I don't think `arr` represents text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115867/discussion-between-guri-copperfield-and-tom-blodget).