# How to stop 'for loop' in a fragment 'Android studio"?

Tags: java, android-studio, listview, for-loop, android-tablayout

I have listview in fragment with tablayout the issue is when i use for loop to put data into listFragment it will never stops the item will repaet if i move between tabs or fragment here is my code. thanks for help.

[when start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55eZ6.png)

[when i move between tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iN5Ze.png)

```
int [] imag = {R.drawable.current, R.drawable.current, R.drawable.current, R.drawable.current, R.drawable.current};
    String[] storynum = {"11111", "22222", "33333", "444444",
            "555555"};
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> lst = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    SimpleAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (int i=0; i<imag.length; i++){
            hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hmap.put("storynum", storynum[i]);
            hmap.put("imag",Integer.toString(imag[i]));
            lst.add(hmap);
        }


        String[] in = {"storynum","imag"};
        int[] out = {R.id.txtloc, R.id.imgvi};
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), lst,R.layout.listview_layout, in, out);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Comment: What does your Fragment actually intend to do? It does NOT create a view, but it is setting an adapter for *something* that probably doesn't exist.,

Comment: wut do u mean? it works fine with fragement name in xml and it shows Toast massage all work fine only it repeat it self .

Comment: my code works fine i just want to stop for loop, each time i return to fragment it just add same items over and over

Answer (score 0):

First do you wanna clean up your formatting a little? (lots of new lines), this can help you get more responses and less down votes.

Second I think the issue is likely somewhere with the implementation of onCreateView.

Under the "onCreateView" line, can you add this:

```
 ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_announcements_page, container, false)
```

Replacing the R.layout.your_fragment_layout_here with your own.

Then your return statement should just be :

```
return view;
```

I do not know what your return statement is/does, but I would assume it just keeps calling onCreateView endlessly.

Comment: srry for the formatting.I tried this the app creshes on start.

Comment: i tried to use if(i>length) break; and onResume but no thing

Comment: I made a tiny change, but what does the error say in your Logcat?

Comment: same thing the app stop on start. i thing there is no code error with my code i posted the app work fine only it repeted item each time i move between tabs. logcat shows no system.errors.ty for ur time.

Comment: JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal continuation byte 0xe,  java_vm_ext.cc:542]     string: 'H�' ,input: '0x48 0xc5 <0x0e>'  read: unexpected EOF! that is my logcat

Comment: That is a little out of my scope, but with the power of Stack Overflow your solution might be here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38030959/cannot-encode-to-utf-8-in-jni   - also can you post the line your error is appearing at too?

Comment: hi my friend i found a solution it was simple ;) just added my code under  if (view == null), ty u :).